# Different results when putting code in .htaccess compared to httpd.conf

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm having this piece of code in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pic=$1
```

Which does exactly what I want it to do. If I visit mydomain.com/345 it would be the same as if I would have typed mydomain.com/index.php?pic=345, and print_r($_GET) returns this:

```
Array ( [pic] => 345 )
```

However, when I try to put this exact code in my precompiled conf-file, instead of a .htaccess file, it returns the full internal path to the file instead, including the $_GET parameter, as such:

```
Array ( [pic] => var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs/345 )
```

Sure, I can just fetch the last part of that string or make it use REQUEST_URI to get the data, but that wouldn't be solving the issue, just moving around it. Anyone knows why it's doing this? I'm guessing it has to do with the fact it is compiling the path internally?

Here's the full conf file in case you need it, I only switched out the domain name to keep it somewhat neutral. :-)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@mydomain.com
    ServerName mydomain.com

    # Indexes + Directory Root
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs/

    # CGI Directory
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/mydomain.com/cgi-bin/
    <Location /cgi-bin>
            Options +ExecCGI
    </Location>

    # Logfiles
    ErrorLog /var/www/mydomain.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/mydomain.com/logs/access.log combined

    <Location />
           RewriteEngine On
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
           RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pic=$1
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT**

I "solved" it by replacing:

```
<Location />
```

with this:

```
<Directory /var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs>
```

However, I'm still curious as to why <Location /> didn't work, anyone have an idea?

Comment: If you’re expecting integer values, use `\d` instead of `.`.

Comment: I'm expecting both chars and numbers, 345 was merely an example value. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

The [latest (apache 2.2) documentation of mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is now clearly stating Location directives should be avoided (search Location in the page). You can see some interesting mails on that [the users httpd mailing list](http://old.nabble.com/-users@httpd--Rewrite-inside-Location-directive-td31297961.html). But this was not stated for example [in the 2.0 documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

> Although rewrite rules are syntactically permitted in  and  sections, this should never be necessary and is unsupported.

So it seems you were on a mysterious unpredictable way of running mod-rewrite, which is certainly a frightening place to live. Thanks for that question now I'm aware :-)

Comment: Hmm yes, I did see that part while I was looking around for a solution. Do you think my current solution with <Directory ...> is better then or should I go for something else?

Comment: Yes Directory is the official equivalent of a .htaccess in a Directory. In your Location Case a rewriteBase instruction would have maybe fix the problem (telling mod-rewrite which directory prefix should be removed form the path, read rewriteBase documentation you'll get good hints of what happened with the Location instruction).